# Extract and merge nested fields from a typescript interface into a new type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way to build a construct similar to:

```js
type typesX = Extract('sys.content.sys.id', [A, B])
```

That would build the union of a set of values coming from a set of types?

I have a typescript types that looks something like this:

```js
export interface A {
  sys: {
    id: string;
    content: {
      sys: {
        id: "someId";
      };
    };
  };
}

export interface B {
  sys: {
    id: string;
    content: {
      sys: {
        id: "anotherId";
      };
    };
  };
}
```

I would like to produce:

```js
type itemID = "someId" | "anotherId";
```

The code is generated and there are a lot of classes, so I'm looking for a construct such as:

```js
type typesX = Extract('sys.content.sys.id', [A, B])
type typesY = Extract('sys.content.sys.id', [B, E, F])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be possible in next version of typescript (4.1) when the [template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) and [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) will be released:

```
type PropType<T, Path extends string> =
    string extends Path ? unknown :
    Path extends keyof T ? T[Path] :
    Path extends `${infer K}.${infer R}` ? K extends keyof T ? PropType<T[K], R> : unknown :
    unknown;

type Extract<Path extends string, Types extends any[]> =
    Types extends Array<infer T> ? PropType<T, Path> : never;

type ItemId = Extract<'sys.content.sys.id', [A, B]> // "someId" | "anotherId";
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200921#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8AoOOAZwE8KAuYs8xAE3opimQHMBuR87BBTAU9UkybU6DCRISs4AIgoQAtsACSzRX1lwAvrqaHGJ-SRKhIsRMIw48AIRmUaY-izYduRgUNSiLhJS7nrk8vSKmEgQMAAWaFo6HuQmEmkGfOYkMFRgeAAKUBBgACp5wAA8pQA0cAWY8XCgAcwUlN5IXAB8cAC8HuycXc0gre0NTQD8cACuSADWMQDuSHC0HpNxo%20NwC8BUEOhwpXAzpQDaWwC665uN2y0ibXAABgAkRMjoaHAA0voAHSfb6-ABK%20leZ3%20O2e7X2h2OpxmRRK5Xy1Quf2udTBvXo8yWEFWdwkhJWSD4OQqcAAomMoDgYJUtrCkC8htw6ujgO0nuz2tEqBdrr0%20icKnyxnCCFBGVRKqCoCdeijimUKtU6lt8XAkMAAG5oKm5fJwDSoVRafp0hlMyoAcikgMEwhQgOd8gddQu%20DqjlFcAA9EGlCp1Ek4AAfJTRWIJKBJHhAA)